# Navigation menus aren't working despite using HTML Tidy

Tags: css, navigation

I am having heck of a time getting navigation menus to work correctly on my webpage. I corrected errors using HTML Tidy like someone suggested in another post, and then I input the CSS codes for the navigation bar I wanted to use. At first the menu wasn't showing at all, but my layout was still in tact like it was prior. So I did HTML Tidy again to see if the HTML needed cleaned up. When I did it that time the navigation menu DID show up, but my layout is all out of sort. I was just curious if due to the nature OF my layout, where I want my navigation menu above the graphic banner, if that's why it's just not working and is all out of wack.

Example of what it does to my page after doing HTML Tidy and showing the menu:

http://veterinarycare.atspace.cc/index3.html

Example of what my page normally should look like:

http://veterinarycare.atspace.cc

It is extremely maddening because I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried to use what seems to be a very simple CSS navigation menu and it just will not work. Any help?

Comment: It looks terrible in every browser except IE 7. Is that what you want?

Comment: Actually I had just looked at it in IE and it did look pretty bad. I never use IE so I was never aware til now. I use Firefox and it looks good on that browser. But I don't have the other browsers so I have no way to know what it looks like. Are you referring to the index.html page and not the index3.html? I also just looked at it in Chrome since that's what my boyfriend uses and it looks fine in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are engaging in many bad practices that simply won't be solved by tidying up your HTML.

The worst offender in my quick scan was this:

```
<div class="extra">
  <span><img src="images/header-img.png" class="png" alt=""></span>
</div>
```

The naming convention for `.extra` makes no sense, the use of the `<span>` is superfluous, and the `.png` class is just odd.

You just need to learn better HTML/CSS practices and try again. Read some books, learn from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap), and lean on StackOverflow when you run into specific and clearly-defined issues.

Comment: This is actually purely a template that I am using. I just wanted something to get my site up and running and when my creative juices are flowing, then I'm going to take the time to come up with a layout that I can start from scratch and actually know what the heck is going on. So no suggestions as far as fixing any of those issues?

Comment: There's really too much wrong for us to just simply rewrite it for you, or even start to tell you where you're going wrong. My suggestions stand.

Answer (score 0):

your html is very much wrong

remove this script from your css file and put it in the head or in separate JS file

```
sfHover = function() {
var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
    sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
        this.className+=" sfhover";
    }
    sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
        this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
    }
}
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
```

the script is targeting #nav, and there is no id='nav' in your html
wrap your navigation in a #nav div.. hope it may work